# Bug/issue tracking integration with Cruise control

Tags: tfs, nunit, continuous-integration, nant, bug-tracking

I am putting together a bunch of applications to create an automatic building for microsoft platform (the products I chose and the software I will build, both, runs on windows). The products I've chosen are:

- Code repository: SubVersion
- Continuous integration: CruiseControl
- Unit testing: NUnit
- Test coverage: NCover
- Static code analysis: FXCop

Now I need to choose a bug/issue tracking system (free if possible) that can be, in some way, integrated with the previous products. 
What I mean by integration? Well, all these products have a file as output I want to be able to publish errors and bugs found by them into the tracking system.
Do you know some product, some technique or trick that can help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, these are all tools I have experience with and congratulate you on your choices - these tools will serve you well if you use them wisely.

The most common usage of these tools is that CC would fail the build if certain criteria are not met, e.g.:

- A unit test fails
- Code coverage falls below a certain threshold
- FXCop detects a violation of a certain severity

Because the build would fail and in continuous integration a failed build should be fixed immediately, you wouldn't really need to put those issues into a bug tracking system.   Think of build-failing errors as being as severe as the code not compiling - you drop everything and fix right away.